# Which one is correct - run off or run off from?

Tags: vocabulary, phrasal-verbs

They ran off the burning car before it exploded.

or

They ran off from the burning car before it exploded.

Comment: Neither. Liquid _runs off_ something. Use _ran from_ or _ran away from_. If you are learning English, you might find https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions a more suitable forum.

Comment: Hi @KateBunting, Run off also means leaving a place or situation suddenly.  Just google it and you'll see.

Comment: Yes, as a native speaker I know that - but, when used in that sense it doesn't take a direct object. You could say _They ran off before the car exploded_.

Comment: @KateBunting, Can I say "They ran off the car before it exploded"? Is it incorrect?

Comment: No, you can't - that's what I meant by 'doesn't take a direct object'. Rain runs off a roof - a person escaping just runs off.

Comment: I would make that an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some historical and current examples of 'run off from' followed by a noun phrase, so I'd say why not, though the meaning seems closer to 'left without permission' in most cases.

> among the pack of stout hounds was a little terrier, that **ran off
> from the plantation**, and, apparently out of pure mischief, kept up
> with the running dog (Harpers, 1855)
>
> I **ran off from my recitations** for the sole purpose of hearing Lincoln (North American Review, 1898)
>
> He used to say he was under fire when he **ran off from the army**, and his ability to slick himself out of anything that wasn't good for him stayed with him for as long as I knew him. (The color of water :a Black man''s tribute to his white mother; McBride, James, 1957-)
>
> He whispered accusingly in her ear, " You **ran off from home** and didn't think about us. (Southern Review, 1999)
>
> After stopping briefly, the man then **ran off from** police when they began to search him. ([Independent](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/crime/man-dies-after-being-hit-by-train-in-willesden-green-police-pursuit-8936417.html#:%7E:text=After%20stopping%20briefly%2C%20the%20man%20then%20ran%20off%20from%20police%20when%20they%20began%20to%20search%20him.%20))
>
> "She **ran off from where she was**, and when she was found she was having breathing difficulties and is now having what appears to be a P.T.S.D. reaction". ([The New Yorker](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2016/09/12/the-ayahuasca-boom-in-the-u-s#:%7E:text=%22She%20ran%20off%20from%20where%20she%20was%2C%20and%20when%20she%20was%20found%20she%20was%20having%20breathing%20difficulties%20and%20is%20now%20having%20what%20appears%20to%20be%20a%20P.T.S.D.%20reaction%22.%20))

Answer (score 1):

Neither is correct - to *run off* is to run away or leave suddenly, but it is normally used without an object.

> The criminal resisted arrest and ran off.

It's better to say *They ran [away] from the burning car before it exploded.*

*Run off* can be used with an object when referring to a liquid.

> The rain was running off the roof.